# Blank Window When Editing in Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Got the problem with editing contents in `elementor`.
Do you know how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of info is missing here. Have you tried anything to fix this issue?

1. Have you checked the inspectors console log for any JavaScript errors?
2. Did you disabled all of your plugins?
3. Switched to a different theme?

The above steps are the first steps to undertake for debugging issues like this.

Comment: its working fine on another theme but when i switch its not

Comment: i tried to disabled all of plugins

Comment: Then most likely it's a conflict in your (child)theme. I do not have a solution for this, since this can be caused by anything.